# Package Manager Migration scripts/hotkeys in Visual Studio

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio, migration

I'm working with Entity Framework migrations in Visual Studio through the Package Manager and some of those commands can get quite long and be prone to  error.  Is there some way to write scripts for the Package Manager or build some kind of hotkeys to bypass entering those commands.  My guess is that this has something to do with PowerShell scripting but I'm just not sure.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are there specific commands that are causing you the most problems?